# Performing apt-key commands with python apt API

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I'm working currently on installing packages via python and some packages require adding repository.

I resolved how to add repository with aptsources. However, I don't know how to add gpg key (something that I'd normally do with `apt-key` command).
Is there dedicated API for that command or should I do that in some other way?

Comment: apt is platform specific so there is no functional reason to not use the system API. If you feel okay about that, for python 3, look at subprocess.getoutput. You will have to handle the prompt for permission but that is a standard operation too.

Comment: Running shell commands from python is highly anti-pattern way of writing code. Apt has it’s python module that allows to communicate with various components and I’m looking for something done that way.